# Google cloud access mongo deployed on compute engine from app deployed on kubernetes engine

Tags: mongodb, google-app-engine, kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I have three instances for kubernetes cluster and three instances for mongo cluster as shown here:

[image]

I can access my mongo cluster from app console and other compute instances  using uri like this:

```
mongo mongodb:root:passwd@mongodb-1-servers-vm-0:27017,mongodb-1-servers-vm-1:27017/devdb?replicaSet=rs0
```

I also tried replacing instance names with internal and external ip addresses, but that didn't help it either.

But the same command does not work from instances inside the kubernetes cluster. I assume that I have to configure some kind of permissions for my cubernetes cluster to access compute instances? Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I managed to find a solution, not sure if the best one.

First we add firewall rules to allow mongodb traffic

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-mongodb --allow tcp:27017
```

Then we use external ip's to connect to mongodb from kubernetes instances

```
mongodb:root:passwd@<ip1>:27017,<ip2>:27017/devdb?replicaSet=rs0
```